# Como quitar o poner una clase a un elemento cuando haga click en otro

Tags: javascript

Hola amigos estoy tratando de agregar la clase css focus a un elemento y que la quite de otro cuando se haga click en el elemto seleccionado. Es hacer un focus pero con vanilla js

```js
let cuadros = document.querySelectorAll('.cuadro');

for (let [i, cv] of cuadros.entries()) {
    cv.addEventListener('click', function focus() {
        cv.classList.toggle("focus")
        if(i+1){
            
        }
    })
}
```

```css
.cuadro {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: lightseagreen;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.focus {
  background: red;
}

.nofocus{
  background: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="cuadro " id="1" >hola</div>
      <div class="cuadro " id="2" >como</div>
      <div class="cuadro " id="3" >estas</div>
      <div class="cuadro " id="4" >tu</div>
    </div>

  
  </body>
</html>
```

El objetivo es que cuando haga click en un item ese se coloque de color rojo y el otro vuelva a la normalidad.

espero me puedan ayudar. gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma de resolverlo es creando una función que haga *reset* antes de hacer agregar la clase `focus`, por ejemplo:

```js
let cuadros = document.querySelectorAll('.cuadro');

for (let [i, cv] of cuadros.entries()) {
    cv.addEventListener('click', function focus() {
        resetFocus();
        cv.classList.toggle("focus")
    })
}

function resetFocus() {
  cuadros.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("focus"));
}
```

```css
.cuadro {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: lightseagreen;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.focus {
  background: red;
}

.nofocus{
  background: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="cuadro " id="1" >hola</div>
      <div class="cuadro " id="2" >como</div>
      <div class="cuadro " id="3" >estas</div>
      <div class="cuadro " id="4" >tu</div>
    </div>

  
  </body>
</html>
```